# Setup a custom domain on StackMob

Tags: stackmob

StackMob allows you to setup a custom domain. All you have to do is add a CNAME record for a wildcard '*' pointing to stackmobapp.com

I set it up on my domain registrar 24 hours ago, but it still doesn't resolve. It is going to my web hosting providers server instead of stackmob's server when I type dev.mydomain.com

I kept my nameservers the same (ns1.myisp.com and ns2.myisp.com).

Do I have to change these to something else?

update: its been over a week and my dev.domain.com dont' go to stackmob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I have to use my registrars name servers, not my own in order to add A/CNAME records to it.

There is one problem with stackmob though, http://example.com doesn't forward to stackmob, only www.example.com and dev.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change your nameservers. Likely the dns changes hadn't propagated to your nameservers yet.  It's been known to take up to 72 hours.

Comment: it's been a week, still nothing.

Comment: Strange.  I assume you double-checked your CNAME record with your domain registrar?

Comment: You have to use registrar's nameservers, I figured out.